# Getting a dangling pointer by returning a pointer from a local C-style array

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, undefined-behavior

I am a bit confused by the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

const char* f()
{
    const char* arr[]={"test"};
    return arr[0];
}

int main()
{
    auto x = f();
    std::cout << x;
}
```

In my opinion, this code should be UB (undefined behaviour). We return a pointer to a C-style array element inside a local scope. Things should go wrong. However, none of the compilers I tested with complain (I used `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` on both g++ and clang). `valgrind` does not complain either.

**Is the code above valid or is it UB as one would think?**

PS: running it seems to produce the "correct" result, i.e. displaying "test", but that's not an indication of correctness.

Comment: FWIW the reason it "works" in practice is that the constant-string "test" is being stored in the executable's static-data area, and thus the string remains valid even after the function returns.  (Whether or not it's guaranteed to work by the language spec is another issue, of course)

Comment: No harm in asking these things, and this question is well-written. +1.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I know what UB is, and the fact that the moon may explode because of it. I'm asking if the code is really UB. And it looks like it's not. And it looks like quite a few out there believes the code is UB... So I think the question is useful.

Comment: @Bathsheba It looks we're still learning here :) Indeed the code **is not UB**.

Comment: @vsoftco: Didn't think it was, but it takes an expert like Barry to point out why.

Comment: @Bathsheba Indeed

Comment: @TypeIA Yes, I saw it. Probably I got too used to the auto-judging the questions, based on seeing the question including pointer returned from function :/

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius No worries, I realized that the title may be a bit off/ do my homework kind of question, but it was really describing the problem. If you're convinced the answer is correct I think it's a good idea to delete your comment, so readers can find the answer quicker.

Comment: @Bathsheba I think you can just remove the comment now so we don't pollute the question

Comment: It's important to realize that, even if no available compiler issues a diagnostic and all available compilers generate machine code that does what one expected the program to do, that _still_ doesn't mean the program doesn't have UB.  Most of the arguments about compilers being "overzealous" with optimizing based on UB concern constructs that were _always_ UB since 1989, but compilers have only recently become sophisticated enough to notice. And in several cases where the standard says something is UB, it's because precise diagnostics would involve solving the Halting Problem.

Comment: @zwol Sure, the question here is whether this is UB or not. I'd have guessed it's UB, but it's not, as far as I can see from the answer and comments.

Comment: @vsoftco Right, in this case it happens not to be.  I'm just saying that the test you performed is inconclusive.

Comment: Why use char* in C++? use std::string instead. They are memory safe.

Comment: You never return a pointer to the local array. You return a copy of a value which was stored in a local array , there's nothing wrong with that

Answer (score 79, accepted):

No, it's not UB.

This:

```
const char* f()
{
    const char* arr[]={"test"};
    return arr[0];
}
```

Can be rewritten to the equivalent:

```
const char* f()
{
    const char* arr0 = "test";
    return arr0;
}
```

So we're just returning a local pointer, to a string literal. String literals have [static storage duration](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex#string-8), nothing dangles. The function really is the same as:

```
const char* f()
{
    return "test";
}
```

---

If you did something like *this*:

```
const char* f() {
    const char arr[] = "test"; // local array of char, not array of char const*
    return arr;
}
```

Now *that* is UB - we're returning a dangling pointer.

Comment: "String literals have static storage duration" - I know all the compilers do this; but is it really in the standards that string literals MUST be with static duration?

Comment: @UKMonkey Yep, added the reference.

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but the same thing should be true for C, right? Initially that's how I bumped into the issue.

Comment: @vsoftco As far as I'm aware. I'm not 100% sure what C does with its literals, I'm a C++ dog all the way - but that seems like a reasonable guess at least.

Comment: @Barry Thanks Barry, I can just search on a C standard now. I'm quite convinced things are OK now.

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but that's not really "equivalent". Functionally, in this context, sure, but an array is an array is an array. ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit :)))) Yes I totally agree.

Comment: Although the quality of this answer is above my pay grade, I've made an edit to soften the "equivalent". I was going to slip in a "broadly" or "functionally" but I think a higher power should do that.

Comment: Well, it does result in exactly the same instructions generated and exactly the same data in memory. So seems quite equivalent to me.

Comment: @jpa In this context, the question is rather whether the standard says it's equivalent, not what some particular compiler did with it :)

Comment: @BartoszKP Yes, and as far as I can tell, the C standard leaves quite little space for any differences here. sizeof(arr) must equal sizeof(arr0) by the standard.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, In both cases, there is a local pointer to `const char`, in both cases the local pointer is initialized to point to a literal string, and in both cases its value is returned. The only difference is, in the original example, the local pointer is a member of a one element array, and in the alternate version, it's a scalar. So what if there is some sense in which those are not "equivalent"?  What matters here is not the exact type of the local variable.  What matters is whether or not the string literal will remain valid after the function returns.

Comment: C does also guarantee that string literals have static storage duration, see http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5p6 .

Answer (score 3):

The array `arr` has local storage duration and will disappear at the end of scope.  The string literal `"test"` however is a pointer to a static storage location.  Temporarily storing this pointer in the local array `arr` before returning it doesn't change that.  It will always be a static storage location.

Note that if the function were to return a C++ style string type instead of a C style `const char *`, the additional conversion/bookkeeping would likely leave you with a value limited in lifetime according to C++ temporary rules.